# Insert source data in target using bucardo

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, bucardo

I want to create sync between two databases using bucardo. It's a one-way sync. Target and source are not identical(schema is same but data is different).

I have setup sync with property onetimecopy=2 but logs shows

```
has rows and we are in onetimecopy if empty mode, so we will not COPY
```

I don't want to delete data at the target, just want to copy data from source to target which is not available on the target.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bucardo documentation for onetimecopy](https://github.com/bucardo/bucardo_org/blob/master/Bucardo/onetimecopy.md) is a bit outdated but `onetimecopy=2` only works when the target is not empty.

Set it to `1` to make a `COPY` from source to target without this limitation but take care with conflicts with the primary key.

For the initial load of data I usually don't rely on Bucardo but in pg_dump or whatever as it seems more easy to understand the process for me.